# Overriding WAR classes directory

Tags: java, ant, war

If you use the Ant to create your WAR via the `war` task, then (as explained [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html)) it will automatically create a `WEB_INF/classes/` directory in the WAR. I would like to change the name of this generated `classes/` directory to, say, `classpath/` and can't figure out how.

If this is possible, would someone provide a code example as well as a reference to the documentation that shows how to do this (I'm curious!). Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why not? It doesn't look like "classes" is a written standard for WAR file structure. And "classpath" is more meaningful (to me at least), because that's what it is - a 1-stop shop for all resources that should be on the classpath, class files, XML files and other resources alike.

Comment: Actually I may be wrong! Please see my comment underneath user384706's response - I have the same question for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change the name of the `classes` to something else.

The directory structure of a `WAR` file is standard and defines a `WEB-INF\classes` for all the .class files of your application

Comment: Can you point me to some official documentation that defines `classes` to be the class file root for a WAR?

Comment: NM - I found it in the Servlet 2.5 spec which can be downloaded [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/)