# Can't get jar file structured the way I want with Ant

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am trying to create a JAR with Ant for the first time and am running into some difficulty. Here is my project directory structure:

```
MyProj/
    src/
        com.me.org
            Fizz
            Buzz
    dist/
        classes/
```

In my Ant buildscript, I am copying all of my source files into the `dist/classes/` folder. Then I am including `dist/classes` as the fileset in my JAR task like so:

```
<jar destfile="dist/myProj.jar">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Sealed" value="true" />
    </manifest>

    <fileset dir="dist/classes"/>
</jar>
```

The JAR task executes and produces a JAR. However, when I put that JAR on the buildpath of another project (Eclipse) and try to use either `Fizz` or `Buzz` inside that other project, Eclipse is importing them as:

> import classes.com.me.org.Fizz;

Etc. This is because Eclipse must think my `classes/` directory is a package!

I assume there's something I can do in the manifest to say "*Hey! The root package is `classes/com/`, not `classes/`!*", so that they will be imported as:

> import com.me.org.Fizz;

I read up on the Ant `<manifest>` task and couldn't find what I was looking for.  Anyone have any ideas what I can do here?

And, if you're curious as to *why* I want to package them under a `classes/` directory, then I'd say its because I like the *idea* of having one single directory inside a JAR that contains the entire classpath. And, especially if there are non-Java classpath resources (images, scripts, files, etc.), you need a place to put both the package root (`com/`) and these other resources inside the same parent directory.

Originally, I was going to call this directory `classpath/`, but then I decided to use the same convention as the WAR file specification, which requires there be a `classes/` directory inside the WAR.

That's why. ;-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think it is a jar convention, that packages have to start at the root and not be put under some directory.

Comment: Not doubting you oers (and thanks!) but can you direct me to some documentation? I'm not seeing that in any of my searches.

Comment: There's no *requirement* that a war file have a /WEB-INF/classes directory (not /classes) at all; all your app's classes could just as well be in a jar. Classes need to be located precisely where their package states they will be (sans custom classloader). Glomming everything together happens during the build process. I don't understand what you think you're accomplishing by trying to impose a non-standard hierarchy.

Comment: Dave you couldn't be **more** wrong. The official Servlet 2.x spec clearly shows classes/ and lib/ to be a standard part of the WAR file directory structure. Link [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/) and see a previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366537/overriding-war-classes-directory).

Comment: @AdamTannon Orly? Every single `/classes` directory in the linked doc is under `WEB-INF/`, which is the first thing that was wrong in your post--it's not `/classes`. If you web app doesn't have any `.class` files, there's no need for a `/WEB-INF/classes` directory. Go ahead--make a war file with only a `index.jsp` at the root level. No `/WEB-INF/classes` directory. No `/WEB-INF/lib` directory. Works fine. Not a requirement. I guess I could be more wrong after all.

Comment: Specification == Standard, but Standard != Requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `Class-Path` attribute to the manifest?  I think adding the following will work:

```
Class-Path : classes/
```

If that doesn't work, then you may have to package a jar containing your classes at the root level and then add that to your myProj.jar.  So you would first create a jar with just your classes, myClasses.jar, then you would package that jar within your myProj.jar.  The manifest would contain :

```
Class-Path : classes/myClasses.jar
```

and your jar would look like this:

```
myProj.jar
  - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  - classes/myClasses.jar
```

I've never actually tried this, so sorry if it doesn't work as expected.  [Here is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) some more info on the Class-Path attribute.

Answer (score -1):

you probably want your ant fileset to be:

```
<fileset dir="dist/classes" includes="**/*" />
```

By just having the directory itself, the "classes" directory is what is put into your jar file.  By putting the includes, you're using classes as a base, and then it takes all the contents of that directory and puts it in the jar.

Comment: I appreciate your input, but I'm pretty sure you didn't read my question! I **want** the `classes/` directory inside my JAR file!